# Jest 'spyOn' TypeScript class without overwriting its properties and functions

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking, ts-jest

Does anybody know how I can `spyOn` a whole class (constructor, and all methods) without overwriting everything (Jest 26.6.3)?

Currently I am trying to SpyOn (not Mock) my Runtime and I only want to check if it got instantiated by Agile correctly:

```
import {
  Agile,
  Runtime,
} from "../../src";
jest.mock("../../src");

// ..

const RuntimeMock = Runtime as jest.MockedClass<typeof Runtime>;

// ..

const agile = new Agile();
expect(RuntimeMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(/* ... */)

// ..
```

but all properties functions of the Runtime get overwritten by Jest, so that it doesn't get instantiated at all.

Is there a way to get a behaviour like the `spyOn` method but with a whole class  because I only want to check if the constructor of Runtime got properly called in the `Agile` class
`expect(RuntimeMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(/* ... */)`

Maybe it's an issue with my import logic because I am importing all classes from one module `internal.ts` and because of that maybe Jest can't recreate the classes properly but I don't know (https://github.com/agile-ts/agile/blob/tests/rewrite-tests/packages/core/src/internal.ts).

Comment: There's no such functionality in Jest and there's no straightforward and safe way to implement it. A lot of times when you need to assert that a function was called, mocking it will result in better test, so this is an edge case. A class is a constructor itself, so spying on it will ruin prototype chain, if there is class hierarchy, it will become broken. That you want it to be spied completely indicates a problem with testing method, spy only on things that need to be spied. If you ever need a constructor to be spied, it could be done with jest.fn that returns real instance.

Comment: When `jest.mock` is used without second argument and relevant `__mocks__` file, it stubs a class, so it works as expected.

Comment: ok thanks.. you are right.. it works quite fine.. my issue was that one class of 5 does drop an unexpected issue because of that I thought it doesn't work at all.. 
And in the specific class it couldn't find a static property after mocking the class.. 
but non static stuff works quite fine.. do you know if there is a solution for that?
Thank you ;D

Comment: This is how Jest automocking works. It does some magic that isn't documented. If you want a mock that works in a specific way then use manual mocks.

Comment: ok.. I only want that some static properties do return some static numbers instad of undefined ;D
But anyway thanks for you help

Comment: You can modify automocked class to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution to it. I ended up creating this code snippet, which can spyOn an entire class, including its constructor. And the usage is also somehow simple, you can add this snippet to a file and import it whenever you need.

Here is the code (typescript/ES6):

```
/**
 * spyOn references to classes. Use it with spyOnClass
 */
export const classSpy: any = {};

/**
 * Utility to Spy On all class methods. Not including the constructor
 * @returns a spyOn references to all the class methods
 * includes the methods mockClear and mockReset as convenience
 * to trigger the respective method for all the spies
 */
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
export function spyOnClassMethods(proto: any): any {
    const properties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto);
    const spyHolder: any = {};
    for (const i in properties) { spyHolder[properties[i]] = jest.spyOn(proto, properties[i]); }
    spyHolder.mockClear = (): void => { for (const i in properties) { spyHolder[properties[i]].mockClear(); } };
    spyHolder.mockReset = (): void => { for (const i in properties) { spyHolder[properties[i]].mockReset(); } };
    return spyHolder;
}
// To attend jest.mock problems, the should start with 'mock'
const mocksSpyOnClassMethods = spyOnClassMethods;

/**
 * Utility to Spy On all class methods and its constructor.
 */
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
export function spyOnClass(mockModuleName: string, mockClassName: string): any {
    classSpy[mockClassName] = {};
    jest.mock(mockModuleName, () => {
        const module = jest.requireActual(mockModuleName) as any;
        const mock = {};
        classSpy[mockClassName] = mocksSpyOnClassMethods(module[mockClassName].prototype);
        mock[mockClassName] = jest.fn().mockImplementation(
            (...args: any[]) => {
                const instance = new module[mockClassName](...args);
                classSpy[mockClassName].constructor = mock[mockClassName];
                return instance;
            }
        );
        return { ...module, ...mock };
    });
}
```

Usage example:

```
import { classSpy, spyOnClass } from './mock-utils';

// This must come before other imports that use ClassName.
spyOnClass('module-name', 'ClassName');

import { ClassName } from 'module-name';

test('this', () => {
    doSomethingThatUsesClassName();
    expect(classSpy.ClassName.constructor).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(classSpy.ClassName.someMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Hope it can help you and others.